# take off programming with a language like Java -- I don't understand this

Tags: comprehension

An excerpt from [*Beginning Java Objects: From Concepts to Code*](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Beginning_Java_Objects.html?id=BF6HyZSN7EsC&redir_esc=y) by Jacquie Barker:

> This is, sad to say, the way many programmers wind up building an OO application when they don’t have appropriate training in the fundamental properties of the building blocks of such an application—namely, software objects. Worse yet, the vast majority of would-be OO programmers are blissfully ignorant of the need to understand objects in order to program in
>   an OO language. So, they **take off programming with a language like Java** and wind up with a far from ideal result: an application that lacks flexibility when an inevitable “midcourse correction” occurs in response to changing requirements after the application has been deployed.

I'm not really sure how to understand that. Any idea?

Comment: That's not the best choice of words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Take off* is used here in the sense that an airplane *takes off*--with a present participle *VERBing* it means "leap into the action named by *VERB*".

The author means that people just jump into writing code before they understand the methodology which a particular language supports.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I thought that "programming" was used as a noun. Thanks a lot.